AWS WAF: Custom Responses are not accessible by browser
I've configured some rules with custom responses in AWS WAF to prevent some users from accessing my website based on their geographical location. I can see that these rules are working as intended because I am able to see the custom response status (406) and response header (custom-header) in the network tab, but I am struggling to find a way for my web client to access any of these values within JS code (using fetch or axios). While using the fetch API, I receive the following error without any response value: TypeError: Failed to fetch.
I've tried using some of the recommended approaches like utilizing a 302 status code + Location header, but these only work for navigation based GET requests, not ajax ones.
Is there any way to do this other than using some proxy web server between the client and  cloudfront?
          fetch(URL, {
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
              ...
            },
            // mode: "no-cors", // Results in opaque response
          })
            .then((res) => {
              console.log("$$$ - res: ", res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log("$$$ - err: ", err); // TypeError: Failed to fetch
            });


